# Can't access JSON value I get undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Unable to get certain values back from JSON.

I'd like to get `result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0].product_brand` when I call it I get undefined.

So I go to check out the structure in console which brings back the following.

`console.dir(result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0]);`

```
'{
"product_id": "1",
"product_name": "Name",
"product_brand": "Brand",
"product_brand_id": "4",
"product_type": "",
"product_type_id": "1"
}'
```

How do I access `product_brand` it always returns `undefined` instead of `Brand` ?

So I looped through the data thinking it was just an empty cell and all of them came back undefined, am I doing something wrong because I feel like I am making the right call as other pieces of data are being returned from archives in the same area.

Comment: Is `result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0]` a string or an object?  You have it inside quotes.

Comment: If what you say is true, then there wouldn't be a bug. The only thing suspicious here are the quotes around the json object. Is it a string?

Comment: can you put your whole json?

Comment: its a converted xml from nodejs (npm: xml2js)

Comment: You can try `JSON.parse(result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0]).product_brand`, because it looks like `result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0]` is a string.

Comment: oh yeah it must be a string

Comment: @Wrokar that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = JSON.parse(result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0]);
console.dir(result.product_brand);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0]` holds a string value. thus, you get an `undefined` when you try to access it's attribute.

A simple and fast way to move ahead would be to do

`var brand = JSON.parse(result.datafeed[0].prod[0].vertical[0].deviceProductJson[0])['product_brand']`